# Group Laravel 8 routes with common middleware

Tags: php, laravel-8

I would like to ask you if it is correct way how to use authentication in laravel 8?

I want to make web which will be visible just for logeddin users.

My solution is here. But I want to know if I will have more routes is there some way how to do it with one command and no need to add for each route?

```
Route::get('/', [PagesController::class,'index'])
    ->middleware('auth');

Route::get('edit/{id}', [PagesController::class,'editPage'])
    ->middleware('auth')
    ->where('id', '[0-9]+');

Route::post('edit/{id}', [PagesController::class,'editItem'])
    ->middleware('auth')
    ->where('id', '[0-9]+');

Route::get('delete/{id}', [PagesController::class,'deletePage'])
    ->middleware('auth')
    ->where('id', '[0-9]+');

Route::post('delete/{id}', [PagesController::class,'deleteItem'])
    ->middleware('auth')
    ->where('id', '[0-9]+');

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use route groups, Laravel's documentation is here; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-middleware

Your example could be updated to:

```php
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [PagesController::class,'index']);

    Route::get('edit/{id}', [PagesController::class,'editPage'])
        ->where('id', '[0-9]+');

    Route::post('edit/{id}', [PagesController::class,'editItem']);
        ->where('id', '[0-9]+');

    Route::get('delete/{id}', [PagesController::class,'deletePage'])
        ->where('id', '[0-9]+');

    Route::post('delete/{id}', [PagesController::class,'deleteItem'])
        ->where('id', '[0-9]+');
});
```

You could go one step further and use [Global Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-global-constraints) to define the `id` as `[0-9]+` on a global level, instead of each route.

Answer (score 1):

At **App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider** define

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
}
```

Once the pattern has been defined, it is automatically applied to all routes using that parameter name:

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', function ($id) {
    // Only executed if {id} is numeric...
});
```

Than you can create route group with middleware('auth')

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
//all of your routes
}
```